# Cannot find variable `_` in Elm

Tags: lambda, elm

I'm used to using the es2015 idiom of `map(_ => _)`, but it seems that a single underscore is not a valid variable name for Elm's lambda functions.

Is this correct?  If so, is there a resource documenting/explaining this?

The following fails with `` Cannot find variable `_` ``

```
view : Model -> Html Msg
view model =
    div []
        [ ul []
            (List.map (\_ -> li [] [ text _.message ]) model.messages)
        ]
```

However this works:

```
            ...

            (List.map (\a -> li [] [ text a.message ]) model.messages)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The underscore is a reserved character that means you will be ignoring whatever value it represents. It therefore cannot be used as if it were a variable in a function's body.

Comment: hey, thanks for that. i can't seem to find documentation for this in any of the online guides I've seen, do you know if there's a canonical resource somewhere?

Comment: I can't find an official explanation in the Elm guides, but Elm descended from Haskell and [inherited the underscore functionality in pattern matching](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Pattern_matching).